# DataGrid not showing Data from datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

So i have been into wpf from 3 days now , and im not able to figur out why the datatable values are not showing up in the data grid , this was not the case for datagridview in windows forms , which iwas using since 10 days

im have tried both programatical and xaml binding , but none of them was working for me

first i had created the datagrid as a seprate user control and had attached the file with the Main Window but the data was not able to be seen , so i thought maybe i should do the testing if the data is shown in the mainwinow itself , then i will septate the datagrid into its own user control, but both of them didnt worked

Here is the MainWindow.xaml

```
<Border> 
  <Grid>
       <Border Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="20" Margin="15,0,15,15" >
                <!-- Apply Style with Rounded Corners to DataGrid -->
                <DataGrid 
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        x:Name="dataGrid"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <!-- Cell Background -->
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#121212"/>
                        <!-- Cell Foreground (Text) -->
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <!-- Grid Lines -->
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveBorderBrushKey}" Color="#1E1E1E"/>
                        <!-- Header Background -->
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}" Color="#2E2E2E"/>
                        <!-- Header Foreground (Text) -->
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="20">
                                            <ScrollViewer>
                                                <!-- ContentPresenter displays the actual DataGrid content -->
                                                <ContentPresenter/>
                                            </ScrollViewer>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Style>
                </DataGrid>
            </Border>
  </Grid>
</Border>
```

Here is the MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DataTable dataTable;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeDataGridAsync();


        }

        private async void InitializeDataGridAsync()
        {
            var newDT = CreateDataTable();
            

            // Simulate a delay for loading data (replace this with your actual data loading logic)
            await Task.Delay(3000);

            // Set the DataTable as the DataGrid's ItemsSource
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = newDT.DefaultView;

        }

        private DataTable CreateDataTable()
        {
          
        // Create a DataTable with columns
        dataTable = new DataTable("MyDataTable");

            // Add 10 sample columns
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add($"Column{i}", typeof(int));
            }

            // Add 100 rows of sample data
            for (int row = 1; row <= 100; row++)
            {
                // Create an array to hold values for each column
                object[] values = new object[100];

                // Assign sample values to each column
                for (int col = 0; col < 100; col++)
                {
                    values[col] = row * 100 + col + 1; // You can change this to your desired data
                }

                // Add the row to the DataTable
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return dataTable;
        }

    }
```

Here is a screen shot for refrecne, the first grey card is where the datagrid is located

[image]

Comment: you seem to have disabled autogenerated columns (AutoGenerateColumns="False") but you do not have any columns defined in your grid. either set it to 'true' or define your own columns

Comment: But im adding it trough code right , so why i even need to do tha manually ?

Comment: well i have tried, even after adding true to AutoGenerateColumns="True" , im still not seing any data

Comment: Did you forget to set your DataContext ?
Try adding "this.DataContext = this;" in your constructor after InitializeComponent.

Then try again using bindings

Comment: And according to documentation --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.defaultview?view=net-8.0

You can directly bind the datatable to the DataSource property of your datagrid instead of using the DefaultView property of DataTable.

Comment: "this.DataContext = this" , its still not showing data , i have added that in the  public MainWindow() after InitializeComponent();

Comment: @VasantRaval, DataGrid template is broken, if you remove that ControlTemplate setter, you will get data

Comment: @ASh Yes after removing the entier DataGrid.Style im able to see the datagrid, but now im concern about the corner radius again

Comment: FWIW I think it's quite difficult to make a data grid look good with rounded corners. I would check requirements. You will be chopping off corner bits aren't really designed to look ok chopped off. Or leaving a gap so the rectangular data grid fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ControlTemplate` for the `DataGrid` is wrong. There is no chance for the `DataGrid` to display any data.

The `DataGrid` is an `ItemsControl`. As such, it must contain an `ItemsPresenter` and not a `ContentPresenter`.

`ContentPresenter` is for `ContentControl` and `ItemsPresenter` is for `ItemsControl`.

The `DataGrid` template is more complex than a simple `ItemsPresenter` as it has e.g. column headers etc. to show.

You can find the Style for the `DataGrid` at [Microsoft Docs: DataGrid Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#datagrid-controltemplate-example).
Or use the Visual Studio XAML designer to edit a copy of the original Style (by right clicking on the `DataGrid` element in the designer view).
Or use Blend to edit the default `Style`.

---

As a note: don't call async methods from the constructor. A method is async because it is considered long-running (enough to freeze the main thread). And long-running methods should not be executed from the constructor. Constructing an instance must be a brief operation (the constructor must return fast and not block the thread).

Instead, defer the long-running initialization routine. Use the constructor to initialize the property to a useful default and execute the long-running initialization routine later.
This has a few advantages:

- initialization code can be asynchronous
  (asynchronous methods can be properly awaited using `await`)
- expensive resources can be allocated when actually requested
  (to avoid heavy instances that allocate unused resources)
- initialization can be further customized (increased flexibility in general)
- instantiation of the type is no longer a blocking operation
  (blocking is an unexpected constructor behavior)
- in the UI context you can avoid freezing (bad UX)
- better testability for unit tests as expensive initialization can be explicitly avoided

Just to name a few. You surely find more.

Deferring the initialization of a `FrameworkElement` or its dependencies is especially easy, as we can use the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event for this purpose. This has another advantage: you can now show a busy indicator on the UI to avoid giving the user the feel that the application hangs (which it actually would had the long-running routine ran in the constructor).

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  this.Loaded += OnLoaded;

  // Return quickly 
  // to make instantiation of this type a non-blocking operation
}

private async void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs)
{
  // TODO::Show busy indicator

  // Properly await the async operation
  await InitializeDataGridAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , well beside of styling im facing more big problem which is slow scrolling with big data in the datagrid, as im taking data from user (in datatable) im about to expect any technically possible amount of data , as you can understand from the name it says "DataTable Visualizer"

When i was using DataGridView with WinForms while DoubleBuffering = true its was smooth copared to datagrid in WPF

Could you help out with that ?

https://codeshare.io/4ezbWE

Comment: The DataGrid has row virtualization enabled by default. Normally, big data sets are no concern for the control. This means you don't have to set any `VirtualizingPanel` attached properties to make it work. If you don't know what those properties are doing you can even cause harm. For example, you set `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit` to `Pixel` what effectively disables UI virtualization.

Comment: The point is, in order to control the visible number of items (item containers) the panel must measure the by index and not pixel. It's difficult if not impossible to efficiently calculate all visible items by their pixels if item size can vary. That's why the `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` must be `true` and the `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit` must be `Unit`. The scrolling is what triggers the virtualization/realization of containers. Therefore, scrolling or measuring in general must be item based and not pixel based.